# Getting resolveLocalFileSystemURL to return true or false (Cordova)

Tags: html, file, api, cordova

I'm trying to get `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` to return a true or false, so that I can use it synchronously in another function.

E.g, I would like to do.

```
function fileExists(file) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file,
    function(entry) {
        console.log('it exists');
        return true;
    }, 
    function(err) {
        console.log('no sign of it');
        return false;
    });
}

if (fileExists(file)) {
    // it exists
} else {
    // doesn't exist
}
```

I'm using this in an iOS app I'm developing using Cordova. I am having no trouble getting the function to console.log, but I can't get a return value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for an alternative. I came up with the following solution:

```
function fileExists(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file,
      (entry) => {
        resolve(entry)
      },
      (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}


await fileExists(file)
  .then((entry) => {
    // file exists
    return true
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // file does not exist
    return false
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using a callback. I stripped the functions back to barebones, and called them with the addition of a callback.

```
function fileExists(file,callback) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file,
  function(entry) {
    callback(true);
  }, 
  function(err) {
    callback(false);
  });
}
```